# OpenGL FBO Rendering

Tags: opengl

I'm getting some artifacts when I try to use a colour attachment on an FBO. I'm saving my first pass as a texture, then passing it as an input to an anti-aliasing shader. The result is, as below, some weird noise and an enforced black background. The AA is applied fine.

[image: Issue]

```
GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, _hndFBO);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);
GL.DrawBuffer((DrawBufferMode) FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0Ext);
GL.PushAttrib(AttribMask.ViewportBit);
GL.Viewport(0, 0, _intWidth, _intHeight);
//Do rendering here
GL.PopAttrib();
GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, 0);
GL.DrawBuffer(DrawBufferMode.Back);
```

Any ideas? Need more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you clearing the back buffer before you render to it each frame?

I'm assuming magenta is "transparent" in the first picture. If so, the parts of the back-buffer where there is no terrain are not affected. Residual data could very well account for what you are seeing.

Comment: PS: the anti-aliased terrain looks lovely!

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a classic "didn't clear the buffer" issue.

Comment: Fixed it! I was clearing the buffer too early it seems. I had figured that was the issue initially but after trying a few combinations it wasn't helping and I, mistakenly, moved on.

@Ranieri Thanks :) I've got a version with a higher LOD: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=14023991&l=68bc941e7d&id=592045104

Still plenty of work to go...

Comment: (Only started playing with OpenGL this week)

Comment: Hmmm.. spoke too soon. That killed the AA... Ah well. I'll have a poke around. Least I'm sure of where to look now. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed. No, really this time >.>